# How could I take my HC05 Module out of AT Command Mode without disconnecting the Arduino?

Tags: arduino, at-command

I am trying to program my HC05 module on my Arduino Uno to change to different names based on different conditions.

I've got it to change the name while it is in AT Command Mode, and have setup a relay to cut the 5V for 1 second to put the module into AT Command Mode, but now I need to know how to take the module out of **AT Command Mode without disconnecting the Arduino from the power**.

I've tried completely disconnecting the power from the Arduino while it is in AT Com Mode and then putting everything back, but it recognises that it was last in AT Command Mode

What is the command to get out of AT Command Mode?

Answer (score 0):

In your bluetooth module you must have an enable pin, check where it is connected if it is connected to HIGH the module is in AT command mode.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your comment, I have already got it to go into AT Command Mode, but now just need to get it out, so that devices can connect to it.  My module an Enable Pin, but when I set it to low it remains in AT Command Mode.  Thanks